# UI Style Capabilities and Alternatives for InstallShield

Tags: installation, installshield

I am looking for information on an installer software for Windows applications that may support some more advanced UI styles besides the usual and dated gray/squared artifacts popular on the early Windows days. At the moment we use InstallShield for the installation of our software and contacted them for information but after over a week we still haven't heard anything. Below a picture of an installer for mac with some more up to date UI which may in line with what I am looking for.

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try to Advanced Installer (paid) tool. It offers quite a few nice and modern UI styles.

[Check their Surface style here](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/installer-ui.html)